# CHMOD 0777, but Wordpress still not able to write files/folders

Tags: vps, chmod

The day before yesterday I ordered my own VPS. But now I have problems with Wordpress, Wordpress is not able to create a .htaccess by itself, not able to write to it and plugins aren't able to create files/folders.

Support hadn't the time for me, so since yesterday I'm looking for a solution by myself, with no luck.

If I change the CHMOD of all folders and files to 777 or 755, I still cannot write files/folders. So I looked further, the owner/group of my www folder on the vps is webapps:apache. I tried to change webapps to the user "root", "nobody", "apache" and "admin". But nothing worked.

Does somebody else has another possible solution?

Comment: checked SELinux yet?

Comment: Yes I did. It's disabled.

Comment: 1. try lsattr, perhaps there are extended attributes in place.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://bestwordpresswidgets.org/lsattr.PNG

Answer (score 1):

1. check the apache error log
2. try lsattr, perhaps there are extended attributes in place.
3. check php open_basedir parameter in php.ini
4. check php safe_mode in php.ini (if it's an old php)

UPDATE:

1. do an ls -lLd public_html/ (or your DocumentRoot, e.g. /var/www, or whatever)
2. do an lsattr public_html/
3. check apache's owner/group : `ps -ef|grep apache` or `ps -ef|grep http`
4. put inside the documentroot a php like x.php and access it with the browser.

x.php contents:

```
<?php
var_dump(ini_get('open_basedir'));
var_dump(ini_get('safe_mode'));
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

Comment: 1. I don't see anything strange. http://sexydameslingerie.nl/error_log
2. http://bestwordpresswidgets.org/lsattr.PNG
3. open_basedir: /home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/ 
4. safe_mode is disabled

Comment: * do the lsattr inside the DocumentRoot (public_html probably)
* see the updated content in my post

Comment: 1. see http://bestwordpresswidgets.org/screenshot.PNG
2. [admin@vps32483 ~]$ lsattr public_html
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on public_html
3. I can create files trough FTP and access them via the browser, if that's what you mean. Only Wordpress is not able to read files and create files or folders.

Comment: http://sexydameslingerie.nl/x.php
And with ps -ef|grep http I get apache returned. And with ps -ef|grep http I get root and apache returned

Comment: @ErikVandeVen 
1. you are not showing us the dir permissions. Please do ls -lLd public_html
2. open php.ini and add domains/sexydames... in open_basedir

Comment: in open_basedir add the full path. Or just disable it.

Comment: 1) http://bestwordpresswidgets.org/lsld.PNG 
2) open_basedir isn't working :(:( Look at http://sexydameslingerie.nl/, I have added the line. Even when I totally disable open_basedir I'm still not able to write files/directories :(

Comment: Problem is solved. Someone suggested me to install suPHP and all problems are solved! Thanks you for all your help, anyway. Really appreciate it!